# Buildozer Kivy: FileNotFoundError with the buildozer file project.properties

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

For some reason I get a FileNotFound with something called project.properties. I have made an .apk of this project before, successfully. I don't know what is different this time around. It's a buildozer file missing, and thus is supposed to be generated with buildozer. However, it's not.

I have tried renaming my package name, deleting the old buildozer file, and initializing a new .spec file. Nothing has changed the error output. I use `buildozer android debug deploy run` to start building.

This is the debug mode traceback:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.18.4 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'pip install -q --user "appdirs" "colorama>=0.3.3" "sh>=1.10,<1.12.5" "jinja2" "six"'
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /home/zonzon/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /home/zonzon/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /home/zonzon/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Run '/usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=PuzzleApp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3crystax,kivy #,pyrebase,openssl --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir=/home/zonzon/Puzzle490/.buildozer/android/platform/build'
# Cwd /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-master
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (19)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 19 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK
[INFO]:    Got NDK version from $ANDROIDNDKVER
[WARNING]: NDK version was set as r9c, but checking the NDK dir claims it is 10.3.2.
[WARNING]: The build will try to continue, but it may fail and you should check that your setting is correct.
[WARNING]: If the NDK dir result is correct, you don't need to manually set the NDK ver.
[INFO]:    Using Crystax NDK r9c
[INFO]:    Found virtualenv at /usr/local/bin/virtualenv
[INFO]:    Found the following toolchain versions: ['4.9', '5', 'clang3.6', 'clang3.7']
[INFO]:    Picking the latest gcc toolchain, here 5
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[INFO]:    Of the existing distributions, the following meet the given requirements:
[INFO]:     PuzzleApp: includes recipes (hostpython3crystax, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy), built for archs (armeabi)
[INFO]:    PuzzleApp has compatible recipes, using this one
# Build the application #16
# Copy application source from /home/zonzon/Puzzle490
# Create directory /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/.buildozer/android/app
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/screenmanager.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/login.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/yourcoupons.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/ninePieceGame.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/ninePieceGame.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/header.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/gameslist.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/pong.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/test_ninePieceGame.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/gameslist.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/RPS.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/home.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/main.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/RPS.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/findcoupons.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/RPS2.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/firebase.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/pong.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/navbutton.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/manage.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/navbutton.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/yourcoupons.kv
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/findcoupons.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/test_home.py
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/screenmanager.py
# Create directory /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/.buildozer/android/app/images
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/tennis.jpg
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/UnderConstruction.png
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/GameIconTemp.png
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/homeIcon.png
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/settingsIcon.png
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/NavIconTemp.png
# Copy /home/zonzon/Puzzle490/images/NavIcon.png
# Package the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.34.dev0', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 103, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 663, in build_package
    self._update_libraries_references(dist_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.34.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 852, in _update_libraries_references
    with io.open(project_fn, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fd:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/zonzon/Puzzle490/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/PuzzleApp/project.properties'
```

My buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = PuzzleApp

# (str) Package name
package.name = PuzzleApp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3crystax,kivy #,pyrebase,openssl
android.ndk_path = /home/zonzon/crystax-ndk-10.3.2

#hostpython3crystax, openssl, sdl2_image, sdl2_mixer, sdl2_ttf, python3crystax, sdl2, six, pyjnius, kivy, pyrebase, urllib3

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = 


# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little experimenting, I actually got it working by uncommenting the `#,pyrebase,openssl` in the requirements. I had previously disabled those since the features that required their implementation were removed from the app. As it turned out, I still depended on them, which is why buildozer didn't find the file it needed.

Comment: and one small thing is that , don't comment the requirement in the same line ( ? ) , I tried sth like `requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,android,numpy,pillow,opencv==4.5.3,plyer #,EasyProcess,entrypoint2,mss,jeepney,pyscreenshot` but it get error same as you , after making the comment in new line ie. `requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,android,numpy,pillow,opencv==4.5.3,plyer 

#,EasyProcess,entrypoint2,mss,jeepney,pyscreenshot`  it works smoothly  

Answer (score 0):

## Edit your buildozer.spec file

### Step 1

Move *android.ndk_path = /home/zonzon/crystax-ndk-10.3.2* from

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3crystax,kivy #,pyrebase,openssl
android.ndk_path = /home/zonzon/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
```

to

```
# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =
android.ndk_path = /home/zonzon/crystax-ndk-10.3.2
```

### Step 2

Add *android.ndk = 10.3.2* as shown below.

```
# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c
android.ndk = 10.3.2
```

### Step 3

Running the following:

1. `buildozer android clean`
2. `buildozer android debug`
3. If the debug step is successful then run `buildozer android deploy`